# Custom tab in admin panel dotCMS

Tags: java, dotcms

I would like to create specific tab in admin panel. How do i create it?  I find this [website](http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/custom-tabs) but I want to create my own tab. Do you maybe have any information about this?
Thanks for any help

Comment: You can find more information about create custom portlets here: https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/creating-portlets

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating your own custom portlet.All the tabs in admin are portlets.So in order to add your own custom tab, you first need to create a custom portlet,add it as osgi bundle.Then go to CMS tab option ,under tools the custom portlet will be avaiable.